# Hibernate-search with hibernate

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-search

Is it possible to use hibernate search with hibernate but without jpa.
I only use jpa annotation but I don't use entityManager.

In this case, how hibernate search is able to know that he has to index an object when I create a new object in the db using hibernate session.

So far, I just have an entity called "person".
I added @indexed to this entity and now I'm not able anymore to update a person entity in the database. There is an exception when calling session.flush during the transaction that update this entity.

thx a lot.

---

Here is what I did so far,

I added to the hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
  <property name="hibernate.search.default.directory_provider">
  org.hibernate.search.store.FSDirectoryProvider
  </property>
  <property name="hibernate.search.default.indexBase">./lucene/indexes</property>
  <property name="hibernate.search.default.batch.merge_factor">10</property>
  <property name="hibernate.search.default.batch.max_buffered_docs">10</property>

    <event type="post-update">
        <listener class="org.hibernate.search.event.FullTextIndexEventListener"/>
    </event>
    <event type="post-insert">
        <listener class="org.hibernate.search.event.FullTextIndexEventListener"/>
    </event>
    <event type="post-delete">
        <listener class="org.hibernate.search.event.FullTextIndexEventListener"/>
    </event>
```

let's assume the following "version" entity:

```
@Entity
@Indexed(index="indexes/versions")
@Table(name="VERSIONS")
public class Version implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @DocumentId
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
  @Column(name="V_NO", length=10)
  private Integer valueNb;

  @Column(nullable=false)
  @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
  private Date tstamp;
```

This is the method that saves a version:

```
  private Version performUpdateActualOnCreation(Session session, VersionedObject storedObject, String userId, String message) {
    // create new version
    Version version = new Version(userId, message);
    session.save(version);

    // update previous version do the object with the Next Value NB
    if (storedObject != null) {
      storedObject.setNextVersion(version);
      session.update(storedObject);
    } else {
      logger.error("Error: trying to update versioned object which has no previous version!!");
    }

    session.flush();

    return version;
  }
```

The issue comes with the session.flush();
Here is the stacktrace but I don't see nothing inthere.:
(I can also see that the index file is created 'indexes/versions' but it's empty)

```
DEBUG 2010-11-02 17:26:33,368+0100 http-8889-Processor6 com.data.server.dao.impl.HibernateDao.rollbackTransaction(HibernateDao.java:104) Rolling back Hibernate transaction 
com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.StatusCodeException: The call failed on the server; see server log for details
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.RequestCallbackAdapter.onResponseReceived(RequestCallbackAdapter.java:192)
    at com.google.gwt.http.client.Request.fireOnResponseReceived(Request.java:287)
    at com.google.gwt.http.client.RequestBuilder$1.onReadyStateChange(RequestBuilder.java:393)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor50.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:157)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannel.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannel.java:1713)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:165)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:120)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:507)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:264)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:188)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor44.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:157)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannel.reactToMessages(BrowserChannel.java:1668)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:401)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:222)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Comment: Please change the hibernate version 3.1.1 G.A

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Hibernate Search Documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html/getting-started.html#d0e146):

> If you are using Hibernate directly this can be done in hibernate.properties or hibernate.cfg.xml. If you are using Hibernate via JPA you can also add the properties to persistence.xml.

You can use Hibernate Search either way. Is it necessary to use JPA annotations or could you switch to Hibernate annotations? To get more help on your exception, you should post the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

I have more information...
(+ now I use hibernate annotations)

In the log I can see:

```
[INFO] class org.hibernate.cfg.ExtendedMappings has interface org.hibernate 
.cfg.Mappings as super class
```

I think this is incompatibility with version of hibernate-search.
Here is the dependencies using Ivy

```
<dependency org="org.hibernate" name="hibernate-core" rev="3.3.2.GA" conf="runtime->default,optional;full->sources"/>
<dependency org="org.hibernate" name="hibernate-annotations" rev="3.4.0.GA" conf="runtime->default;full->sources"/>

<dependency org="org.hibernate" name="hibernate-search" rev="3.2.0.Final" conf="runtime->default,optional;full->sources">
   <exclude org="javax.jms" name="jms" />
</dependency>
```

I looked at the hibernate Compatibility Matrix, I saw for Hibernate-core.3.3.2 that Hibernate 3.1.x is compatible.
I'm gonna get the previous version and see what's gonna happen

Comment: I change the version of hibernate search to 3.1.1.GA and that work perfectly :-) thx for your help ;-)